# “Ich habe meinen Bruder zu Flughafen genommen.” – choice of verb

Tags: word-choice

> Ich habe meinen Bruder zu Flughafen genommen.

Is it OK to use the verb *nehmen* in this situation? I don’t know why I think that sentence is a little weird.

What if I use the verb *gefahren?*

Comment: ad 1) zu dem Flughafen => zum Flughafen.

Answer (score 5):

Correct is:

> Ich habe meinen Bruder zum Flughafen gefahren.

This implies, that you used a vehicle and only dropped him off without staying there yourself.

Also working:

> Ich habe meinen Bruder zum Flughafen mitgenommen.

(I gave my brother a lift to the airport)

This could also have been happened by bus or subway and indicates, that you wanted to go to the airport too.

Comment: If you didn't use a vehicle, or if you don't want to stress the fact that you were driving yourself, you can also use "gebracht" instead of "gefahren".

Comment: »Ich habe meinen Bruder zum Flughafen *gefahren*« is unusual in Austria. In Austria you better should use the version using »*mitgenommen*«. Also possible (and more common than *gefahren* in Austria): »Ich habe meinen Bruder zum Flughafen *geführt*«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: I think it is noteworthy to mention that when using these Austrian words in Germany, *mitgenommen* will not cause any trouble, but *geführt* will not be understood in Germany, or will at least be misinterpreted. So, in this case, both words should be remembered.

Comment: Using "mitgenommen" implies that you would have gone there anyways and, since you were going there, you offered your brother a lift. If you did not plan on going to the airport, the first version with "gefahren" would be better.

Comment: *Mitnehmen* can also be split here: ‘Ich habe meinen Bruder **mit** zum Flughafen **genommen.’**

Answer (score 3):

The usage of the pair *nehmen/bringen* differs from that of *take/bring*. In this case you would use *bringen*. You can of course, just as in English, also use a more specific verb like *fahren*, *tragen*, or whatever applies.